# TortoiseSVN how to have 2 separate revision count for 2 projects?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Basically in my SVNrepositories folder I have

```
SVNrepositories/trunk/project1
```

I have created another project and I have put it in

```
SVNrepositories/trunk/project2
```

But project2 start from revisions of the other project1. Why it doesn't start the count from 0 ?

Comment: Don't worry, these are just revision numbers, they are for internal use and there's no difference if they start from 0 or from 10000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the revision number is the revision for the entire repository not a subfolder. If you want separate revision numbers then you need separate repositories.